# CSS : alternative to vertical-align?

Tags: html, css

Is there any alternative to vertical-align?

For using vertical align I am having to set the display to table-cell. When I have the display set to table-cell the height of the div that I have set does not work. I have overflow-y set to auto on that div. What I am trying to do is align the content inside the div from the bottom of that div... I am not able to do that.. Any alternatives?

This is what I have right now:

```
#container{
height:375px;
border:1px solid #000;
position:relative;
overflow-y:auto;
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:bottom;
}

#container > div{
margin:0;
margin-bottom:5px;
width:660px;
position:relative;
}
```

Comment: use display:block; and padding ,margin.

Comment: If you post your code we can `vertical-align` work :) Also you can use absolute positioning or padding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 2 alternatives, one is to set `line-height`.. and other one is to set the parent element to `position: relative;` and than set your child element to `position: absolute;` and later, use `top: 50%;` and `left: 50%;` and than deduct the margins which will be 1/2 of the total `height` and `width` of the `absolute` element itself...

```
.parent {
   position: relative;
}

.child {
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   margin-top: -100px; /* Assuming height of the element is 200 */
   margin-left: -200px; /* Assuming width of the element is 400 */
}
```

---

Here's a catch though, using `absolute` will require fixed dimensions of the element you are trying to `align` vertically `center`

---

Vertical Aligning an element using `display: table-cell;`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jrEL9/)

```
.parent {
    height: 200px;
    background: #eee;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 300px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

.child {
    height: 20px;
    background: #aaa;
}
```

Also it would be better if you use `display: table;` as a wrapping element.

Comment: I would do that.. But the problem is I have more than one div inside the container...

Comment: The code that you gave in the jsfiddle demo worked perfectly .. thanks for the answer ..

Comment: When the content inside the container grows taller, container grows taller with it though I have it set to overflow:auto.. any idea how to deal with this?

Comment: @user1763032 you can throw another question with that issue and a fiddle if possible :)

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
#container{
height:375px;
line-height:375px;
}

#container > div{
display:inline-block;
line-height:1;
}
```

Comment: This is the only "hack" which mimics "table-cell" correctly as it works with any length of text.