# Make a div position bottom of another div

Tags: css, html

I've a div inside another div that wants to show at the bottom. But it wont.
Look at the code:

```
...
<td valign="top" style="height: 900px;">
    <center>
        <div class="sidebar">
              <div id="block_sub">Hello</div>
        </div>
        </center>
</td>
...

<styles>
.sidebar{
position: relative;
}
#block_sub{
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
}
</styles>
```

Comment: Like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20143444/css-alternative-to-vertical-align/20143496#20143496)?

Comment: There is no `styles` element, but [`style`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/document-metadata.html#the-style-element).

Answer (score 2):

Works fine for me:

http://jsfiddle.net/2nssD/

You made two mistakes through:

You used `#sidebar` instead of `.sidebar`, and you didn't give your outer div a height.

Use this:

```
.sidebar{
    position: relative;
    background: red;
}
#block_sub{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    background: blue;
}
```

Comment: cant give sidebar exact height. its dynamic inside dynamic TD actually.

Comment: OK. Still, it works like you wanted it to work. It is stuck to the bottom of the sidebar. If you don't give the sidebar a height, then it will collapse. That's just how the CSS box model works.